# d3 multiple donut chart slice label not presented

Tags: d3.js

I am a bit stuck with D3 multiple donuts. I want to present the label for each slice. Value works fine but not label.

http://jsfiddle.net/brrmek/prnne3y9/

This works:
Row 70:      `.text(function(d) { return d.value; });`
This don´t (It is the label I wish to show...):
Row 70:      `.text(function(d) { return d.itemLabel; });`
Solution:
Row 70:      `.text(function(d) { return d.data.itemLabel; });`

Thanks Baz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` attribute of your selection holds the label:

```
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.itemLabel; });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qswj2Ls/)

Comment: Yes, but it is the label I wish to present not the value. Sorry for being misleading in my question...See the data array freqData. itemValue can be preesnted with value but I want to present itemLabel

Comment: @brrmek Ah, I see. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I think I found it ´d.data.itemLabel´ seems to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the attributes!